# Hibernate Criteria create a count query without asking it beside The query

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I create a query using criteria (java) on PostgreSQL DB ,

This is a snippet from my code:

```
protected Criteria createEntityCriteria() {
    return createEntityCriteria(getSession());
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(Session session) {
    return session.createCriteria(getEntityClass(), "main").setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
}


Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
crit.setFirstResult((pagingInfo.getPageNumber() - 1) * pagingInfo.getPageSize());
 crit.setMaxResults(pagingInfo.getPageSize());
```

now when i view the log from hibernate(criteria query) i see 2 queries
the first one:

the first query which i have **NOT** asked at all is:

```
/* criteria query */ select
    count(*) as y0_ 
from   some_Table this
left outer join  moreTable
on ......
```

the second one is which i did asked for:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* criteria query */ select   col1 y0_,
    col2 y1_,
        ......
    from .....
left join ....
on ....
order by
    y41_ desc limit ? offset ?
```

the problem is that the count query fail due to a query time out .
and second one works perfect  .

is there a way to prevent from hibernate to "made-up" this count query ?

Comment: Looks very suspicious. Could you post all the code that is executed till `crit.list()`?